# What is the location of the configuration file in Neo4J 3.0?

Tags: neo4j

I have recently installed Neo4j 3.0, and since I need to enable outside access, I need the configuration file, and where in the 2.3.3 the configuration files were located in within the /var/lib/neo4j/ structure.

I am not able to locate them anywhere in the 3.0 version. I know it have changed name to neo4j.conf.

My folder structure in the above directory is:

- plugins
- import
- data
- certificates

I am running [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus).
I have tried the documentation. However, that doesn't describe the location. I also already tried "find -name "neo4j.conf" without luck.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[UPDATED]

According to the 3.0.0 [Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations-locations), the default location of the config file for "Debian" is:

```
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was precisely that part i couldnt find.

Comment: whats for mac os?

Comment: I just updated the link in my answer. Click on it to see the table with the locations.