# What is the location of Neo4j.config in Neo4j 3.0.1 for window 7

Tags: neo4j

The error I am getting while opening a database directory in neo4j

[image]

MY Neo4j system folder looks like this

[image]

I need to make changes in the configuration so that i can import one database in it

I have gone through [What is the location of the configuration file in Neo4J 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919507/what-is-the-location-of-the-configuration-file-in-neo4j-3-0) it didn't  help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start your Neo4j Application a popup window opens what contains the button "Options...". If you click on that button you will see where your configuration files is placed.

[image]

[image]

Under the "Database Configuration" you should see the path.
This picture was taken on MacOS but I think it should be the same on Windows.